# Adding JVM Option to maven javafx project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, jfoenix

I'm using IntelliJ Idea, and trying to create an executable or jar of my app but I'm having issue with JFornix

This is how I run the application from the IDE

[image]

but running this from an executable or jar file returns the

```
 module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to module com.jfoenix
```

I tried adding the args this way

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.6</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
         <id>default-cli</id>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.ahs.pos/com.ahs.pos.Launcher</mainClass>
            <arg>--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix</arg>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

it's a similar issue to [this post](https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix/issues/1200) but with gradle, and I'm trying to do this on maven pom.xml

any ideas how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin), the argument should be using `<option>` instead

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.6</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
         <id>default-cli</id>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.ahs.pos/com.ahs.pos.Launcher</mainClass>
            <options>
                <option>--add-opens</option>
                <option>java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix</option>
            </options>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```